# Improving a JavaScript filtering function

Tags: javascript

I created a function that compares an array of letters to the alphabet, and returns the letters that are *not* in the original array.

While this works, it looks somewhat clumsy to me, but I don't know what I'm looking for to improve the code...Is there a way to make it more elegant? Perhaps getting rid of the `notPresent` array somehow?

```
getLettersNotInContent(['z', 'a', 'p']);

function getLettersNotInContent(letters) {
  // Filter dups if present
  var uniques = [];
  letters.filter(function(letter) {
    if (uniques.indexOf(letter) === -1) {
      uniques.push(letter);
    }
  });

  // Filter and return the letters that are not present in the content
  var alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o',
  'p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];
  var notPresent = [];
  alphabet.filter(function(letter) {
    if (uniques.indexOf(letter) === -1) notPresent.push(letter);
  });
  return notPresent;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing up two different ways of doing this. The old-fashioned way involves looping through the alphabet and pushing the letters not present into an array:

```
function getLettersNotInContent2(letters) {
    var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
                    'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
    var notPresent = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
        if (letters.indexOf(alphabet[i]) === -1) notPresent.push(alphabet[i]);
    }
    return notPresent;
}
```

The newer way (more elegant but [not supported in IE8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)) uses the `filter` method with a function that returns true or false:

```
function getLettersNotInContent3(letters) {
    var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
                    'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
    return alphabet.filter(function (letter) {
        return letters.indexOf(letter) === -1
    });
}
```

Your code happens to work because, under the hood, `filter` also loops through the values of an array in turn. But you're not using it in the intended way.

(In both cases I removed the filtering out of duplicates as this seems unnecessary.) ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejmcz/1/))

Comment: Using `indexOf` is actually [quite slow](http://jsperf.com/key-existence). You should probably be building a map first to allow quick lookups.

Comment: @plalx That would be very premature optimisation. We are talking about up to 26 letters. There are unlikely to be performance problems resulting from this function, and building a map is not the most likely solution if there are.

Comment: I would call it writing efficient code rather than premature optimization as it wouldn't make the implementation much more complex and the resulting would be an *O(n)* algorithm rather than *O(n^2)*.

Comment: @plalx No it's actually slower, because in this case you have to make a new hash for each value of `letters`. http://jsperf.com/filter-with-hash-vs-with-indexof. Of course it may depend on the length of letters and whether the hashes can be stored and reused somehow.

Comment: You seem to be right that it isin't true in Chrome, but it really doesn't make any sense. It takes *O(n)* time to create the map, but then lookups takes *O(1)* time. It should definitely be faster. I tested in IE10 for example and the hash runs 30% faster. http://jsperf.com/filter-with-hash-vs-with-indexof/2

Comment: Remember that a well-optimized browser will be implementing low-level code that is usually much faster than anything you can write in js.

Answer (score 2):

Most People don't like regular expressions as they can get extremly complex. but I think this is a perfectly simple example where it could be used.

```
function getLettersNotInContent(letters)
{
    var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";                 // Line 1
    var regexString = "[" + letters.join("|") +"]";              // Line 2
    var regexUnwantedChars = new RegExp(regexString, "gi");      // Line 3
    var resultString = alphabet.replace(regexUnwantedChars , "");// Line 4
    var resultArray = resultString.split("");                    // Line 5
    return resultArray;                                          // Line 6
}

console.log(getLettersNotInContent(["z", "a", "p"]));
console.log(getLettersNotInContent(["a", "b", "c"]));
console.log(getLettersNotInContent(["x", "y"]));
console.log(getLettersNotInContent("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("")));
console.log(getLettersNotInContent("abcdefghijklnopqrstuvwxyz".split("")));
```

I split the function into many lines to make it easy to explain but It needn't be so verbose.

1. you need the alphabet in a string. *(line 1)*
2. create a RegExp object. *(lines 2-3)*
3. remove characters. *(line 4)*
4. split what's left by character. *(line 5)*

compact version:

```
function getLettersNotInContent(letters)
{
    return "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        .replace(new RegExp("[" + letters.join("|") +"]", "gi"), "")
        .split("");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Shortest way i could think of**.

1. theoretically the while-- loop is faster in the most browsers
2. this alphabet has 26 letters so why not set it directly
3. you can jump to a specific letter inside a string in javascript using the index like in arrays
4. the shorthand inverse operater shortens also a little the check inside the while loop

you can pass ['a','x','u'] or 'axu' as letters value

and by replacing `b=[]` & `b.push(a[l])` with `b=''` & `b+=a[l]` you get a string.

then you can split it with `b.split()`.

note: as you use `while--` the letters ar not ordered alphabetically .. to do that you need to invert the `a` string or use `b.sort()`

```
function missingLetters(letters,a,b,l) {//a,b,l = placeholder so no need for var
 l=26;
 a='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
 b=[];
 while(l--){
  letters.indexOf(a[l])!==-1||b.push(a[l])
 }
 return b;
}
```

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/uhqWh/

Answer (score 0):

If we split an alphabet string which looks nicer IMO, and use the "not -1 operator", we get this:

```
function missingLetters( s )
{
  return "abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("").filter( function(c) 
  {
    return !~s.indexOf(c)
  });
}
```